# Response Policy Zone: How to setup a DNS Bind with Docker, with 2 different zones that can be access by 3 different clients in the same server?

Tags: docker, dns, bind9

I need to create a DNS Bind in Docker with 2 different zones for 3 DNS clients from the same server, where:

- **1 client has access to one zone** and **the other 2 access to the other zone**

I need to use Bind9 and Docker for this.

How can i do this?

Comment: RPZ is not to filter which clients has access to what, it is to change the zone content. For changing responses per client, see the bind "view" feature. However you are offtopic here as there is nothing related to programming in this.

Comment: Ok so where i should ask these type of questions?